# Using Python to run an OS command

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am trying to use Python to execute an OS command and wait for any key to be pressed by the user. I expected the following code to execute gracefully...

```
import os
os.system("ls") 
input("Press any key")
```

...however I get the following output after pressing *ENTER*:

```
Press any key
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/test.py", line 4, in <module>
    input("Press any key")
  File "<string>", line 0

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

I am on Python 3.6.3 running on MacOS High Sierra. Any ideas?

Comment: That's not Python 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are actually running your code with Python 2. 
 See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) for python 2, which say:

> **input([prompt])**
>   Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt)).

That is, it will read *and execute* your response as a Python statement.

Compare that to Python 3, in which `input` simply returns your response.

---

Some tests you can do:

1. Run `python`.  Do you see something that looks like this:

   ```
   Python 2.7.13 (default, Sep  5 2017, 08:53:59)
   ```

   Or:

   ```
   Python 3.6.2 (default, Oct  2 2017, 16:51:32)
   ```
2. If `python` gets you python 2.x, try running your code with `python3`.

Comment: You seem to be right! However, I am 100% sure that I downloaded the Python 3.6.3 binaries for Mac. Were the Python.org binaries built wrong? Or do I have to manually configure the runtime to execute Python 3?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've accidentally run it with a Python 2 interpreter. While it works fine in Python 3:

```
$ python3
Python 3.6.1 (default, Jul  4 2017, 10:24:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> input("Press any key")
Press any key
''
>>>
```

Whereas Python 2 tries to eval the response and give a syntax error

```
$ python2
Python 2.7.13 (default, Dec 23 2016, 05:05:58) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> input("Press any key")
Press any key
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 0

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```